# How do I install mingw-std-threads on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, apt, dependencies, mingw

I am downloading the Bitcoin source code for Windows, and trying to compile it using [these](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/11814) steps.

I am receiving these errors when I `make` my Bitcoin source code on `Windows Subsystem for Linux`

`error: ‘mutex’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a type mutable std::mutex mutex;`

It would appear that the `sudo apt install g++-mingw-w64-x86-64` package does not include some important threading stuff I need to run by Bitcoin source code. With a bit of digging, it seems that I need to additionally install `mingw-std-threads`

How do I do this?

Comment: uhm... why're you trying to compile Bitcoin within WSL?  That's bound to have problems.

Comment: uhm... That's one of the standard ways suggested on the Bitcoin Github. https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/build-windows.md

Comment: that link 404s...

Comment: Works for me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you missed a part of the instructions.  On Ubuntu 16.04, you have to run:

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty universe"
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo update-alternatives --config x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ # Set the default mingw32 g++ compiler option to posix.
```

On Ubuntu 17.10+:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ # Set the default mingw32 g++ compiler option to posix.
```